# Connect to VPN from BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, vpn

Is there any way to create a connection to a virtual private network using the BlackBerry APIs?

My understanding is that to connect to a VPN on BlackBerry you need to use bes, create a vpn profile, and so on.  I am looking for a pure app-driven alternative.

Is it possible to do this by using something from the [BBOS 5.0 packages](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer in case someone needs it:

1. There is no API which allows you to create/configure VPN profile. AFAIK if you are in the BES infrastructure it is possible profiles to be created on the server side from administrator and then pushed to clients via Blackberry Push Services. I haven't tried it though!
2. However you can also configure a VPN profile on your blackberry device and set it to a wi-fi connection. Then the Wi-Fi connection automatically goes into VPN as well as all the data you transfer in your app(make sure not to forget to add ;interface=wifi when you call Connector#open())